# Are there any Vulcan ships?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, vulcan

This *Star Trek* question popped up in chat today.  Setting aside *Enterprise*, do we ever see in a *Star Trek* show or movie a Vulcan designed and built ship that was built after the Federation was established?

Comment: The Vulcans probably didn't change things much since their shuttle landed on Earth in "Star Trek: First Contact". They don't seem the sort to fix something that ain't broken. Of course, that was long before the Federation was established.

Comment: I'm sure they do still have a fleet, even a military one, in the same way NATO and UN nations have militaries independent of the united forces, or perhaps in the same way Japan does (local/national defense).

Comment: TNG S7 E5 "Unification", the Enterprise crew attempts to locate a stolen Vulcan ship. In the end, Romulan forces are "escorted" by a few Vulcan vessels. The vessels are shown to the audience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_ship) there were Vulcan ships being used for transport and exploration. For instance, one Vulcan ship ventured into the Gamma Quadrant during the time of DS9.

In the old continuity of the new Star Trek, the Vulcan Science Academy built the extremely fast ship to facilitate Ambassador Spock's attempt to save the Romulan homeworld. The ship (and the time worm hole it created) is the bridge between the old continuity and the new one.

Comment: Is the ship that was sent to heard form again? Say by a certain galaxy-class starship?

Comment: Correction: Geordi LaForge built the squid ship that Spock brought back in time. The Vulcan Science Academy only commissioned it.

Comment: @Plutor is that from the tie-in comics?

Comment: @Keen: Yes, sorry I didn't cite it. It's from the _Countdown_ mini-series, which covers the events just before Spock gets pulled into the black hole. (Whoops, the ship is called the Jellyfish.) Here's a bunch of info on Memory-Beta: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Jellyfish

Comment: It looks like that article admits there's some in-universe disagreement about the provenance of the ship.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the already mentioned *Jellyfish* from the 2009 Star Trek movie, We do see three Vulcan transport ships in the [TNG episode *Unification*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_II_%28episode%29), although Memory Alpha describes them as *Apollo* class Federation vessels.

Also, in *ST:TMP*, we see a [Federation long-range shuttle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Long_range_shuttle) carrying Spock to the *Enterprise*.  Memory-Alpha has this quote from the man who designed the model for the movie:

> "They were hopefully designed to be the new standard shuttle for the movie Enterprise-era. The Vulcan shuttle is actually a Starfleet shuttle, co-designed with Vulcan engineers. That's why it has subtle repetitions of that ceremonial 'gong' shape we saw in "Amok Time".

Perhaps it's reasonable to speculate that once the Federation was formed, Vulcan consolidated their starship design and construction with Starfleet.

Comment: Those ships were *used* by the [Vulcan National Merchant Fleet](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan_National_Merchant_Fleet), but they were actually [Apollo-class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Apollo_class) ships (i.e. built by the Federation).

Comment: Good catch, gnovice.  I've updated my post.

Answer (score 6):

We see Spock has a Vulcan ship in the Star Trek 2009 movie.  Although the movie creates an alternate timeline, his ship is from the original timeline and should then be considered canon.  That being said, in the new timeline I doubt very much Vulcan ships will be seen!

Answer (score 6):

Your question isn't explicit about what you mean by "Vulcan ship" - if you mean Vulcan-designed and built, I can only think of the shuttle NorbyTheGeek mentions, but in TOS there's a Constitution-class cruiser, the USS Intrepid, crewed by Vulcans.

Comment: I've clarified the question.  I'm looking for non-Federation/non-Starfleet ships.

Comment: There was also a Federation ship in DS9 crewed totally by Vulcans. The captain had some sort of long-standing disagreement with Sisko.

Answer (score 3):

Besides ship in *Star Trek: First Contact* movie, I have seen many Vulcan ships in *Star Trek: Enterprise* TV Series before establishment of Federation. They can be identified by ring around ship:

[image: The Vulcan ship appears as a red ring attached to the middle of a long narrow double-pointed hull with a single fat branch from the main hull to the nadir of the ring.]

Comment: The question specifically asked about Vulcan ships built _after_ the founding of the Federation, and specifically _excluding_ Enterprise.

Comment: These ships looked really cool, and moreover, were far ahead from United Earth's designs. It makes little sense to me how quickly the Federations seems to have become dominated by humans, at least as far as the fleet design and composition is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> The [T'Vran](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/T%27Vran) was a Vulcan science vessel that was in service in the mid-24th century. In 2369, the T'Vran was on an exploration mission of the Gamma Quadrant.
>
> In that year, on its return trip to the Alpha Quadrant, the T'Vran offered assistance to the Starfleet runabout USS Ganges, located on the outskirts of the Chamra Vortex. Although its pilot, Odo, required no assistance, he did request to have two Rakhari survivors aboard transported back to Vulcan. (DS9: "Vortex")